# Best way to format select text with wavy red underline?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I am working in a `RichTextBox` and I need to highlight certain text as incorrect (by my own checking). I have crawled all over the web trying to find something- preferably a package or library that I can use to achieve this...

I'm very surprised that this format isn't a default style in the `RTB` font style settings...

Comment: Which frontend technology are you using?

Comment: Sorry for suggesting google, but search for `richertextbox`. Many of them provide such functionality. It involves a bit of p/invoke.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012 for c#. I can't find anything about this functionality so if you have a link that says otherwise feel free to beam me up.

Comment: Sorry Leppie I only just re-read your comment- I read it originally as google richtextbox :-P but now I am getting promising results with richer. Thanks

Comment: This richertextbox looks a bit more sophisticated that what I need.

Comment: @user2067855 -.- I didn't want to know your IDE because it doesn't matter in most cases. Frontend technology means...WPF, Silverlight, ASP .net... so what is it?